# Adding XML Attribute XmlElementWrapper Using JAX-B

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How do I add **attribute** to **XmlElementWrapper**? I find it difficult to do so. I could not find article or tutorials and questions discussing about it.

I would like my XML to be like the ff:

```
<Header>
    <Header2 attr="x">
        <Fields attr="y">
            <Field>
                <field1>a</field1>
                <field2>b</field2>
                <field3>c</field3>
            </Field>
        </Fields>
    </Header2>
</Header>
```

In above XML, **Fields** is an XmlElementWrapper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `@XmlElementWrapper` as its purpose is to avoid extra structures if you have just `Fields/Field` structure in XML.

If you want to capture the attribute, you'll need a class for `Fields` containing `attr` as `@XmlAttribute` and `fields` as `@XmlElement`.

Comment: Looks like I'll be forced to resort to that solution. Thanks for the response.